# Calculate time difference and return only hours and minutes (in VB.net)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I'm developing a system to calculate time difference. How can I compare two time (with date) and get the hours & minutes of the difference?

**Example 1:**

```
datetime1 = 1-Apr-2014 01:05:04 AM
datetime2 = 1-Apr-2014 02:05:04 AM
```

Results will be:

```
datetime2 - datetime1 = 01 Hours 00 Minutes
```

**Example 2:**

```
datetime1 = 1-Apr-2014 01:05:04 AM
datetime2 = 2-Apr-2014 02:15:04 AM
```

Results will be:

```
datetime2 - datetime1 = 25 Hours 10 Minutes
```

A negative value (for datetime1 > datetime2) would also be helpful for indicating that datetime1 is greater than datetime2

**Example:**

```
datetime1 = 2-Apr-2014 01:05:04 AM
datetime2 = 1-Apr-2014 01:05:04 AM
```

Results will be:

```
datetime2 - datetime1 = -24 Hours 00 Minutes
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My recommendation would be to use something like

```
Dim minutesDiff = DateDiff(DateInterval.Minute,datetime1,datetime2)
Console.WriteLine("{0} hours {1} minutes", Math.Abs(minutesDiff) / 60, Math.Abs(minutesDiff) Mod 60)
```

To extend this to seconds:

```
Dim secondsDiff = DateDiff(DateInterval.Second,datetime1,datetime2)
Console.WriteLine("{0} hours {1} minutes {2} seconds", Math.Abs(secondsDiff)/3600, (Math.Abs(secondsDiff) Mod 3600) / 60, Math.Abs(secondsDiff) Mod 60)
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the suggestion. How can I calculate both hours and minutes by using your method? thanks

Comment: Both are already calculated there, try running it. By dividing minutes by 60, you'll get hours difference, and by using Mod you get the remaining minutes.

Answer (score 4):

Another way, you can use `TotalHours` and `Minutes` property of `TimeSpan` object resulted from subtracting two `DateTime`s :

```
Dim d1 As DateTime = DateTime.Now
Dim d2 As DateTime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(25).AddMinutes(10)

Dim difference As TimeSpan = d2 - d1
'round down total hours to integer'
Dim hours = Math.Floor(difference.TotalHours)
Dim minutes = difference.Minutes
'Following line prints : 25 Hours 10 Minutes'
Console.WriteLine("{0} Hours {1} Minutes", hours, minutes)
```

Answer (score 4):

Solutions to my question is:

```
Dim d1 As DateTime = DateTime.Parse("1-Apr-2014 10:10:00 AM")
Dim d2 As DateTime = DateTime.Parse("2-Apr-2014 10:10:00 AM")
Dim difference As TimeSpan = d2 - d1
'round down total hours to integer'
Dim hours = Math.Floor(difference.TotalHours)
Dim minutes = Math.Abs(difference.Minutes)
Dim seconds = difference.Seconds
Dim timeleft As String = Format(hours, "00") + " h " + Format(minutes, "00") + " m " + Format(seconds, "00") + " s "
If Int(seconds) < 0 Then
     timeleft = "00 h 00 m 00 s (Time Out)"
End If
Return timeleft 
' timeleft 24 hours 00 minutes 00 seconds
```