# Time comparison and difference in vb

Tags: vb.net

How to compare between  current time and a past time in vb and check if the duration time is less than 30 mins or not ?

Example :
Current time : 11:30am
Time : 11:00am
Duration : 30 min (time should be less than 30 mins. )

If the time duration is exactly 30 min difference 
Return true 
Else false

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate time difference and return only hours and minutes (in VB.net)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22879310/calculate-time-difference-and-return-only-hours-and-minutes-in-vb-net)

Answer (score 0):

```
If (Date.Now - myDateTime) < TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30) Then
    'Time difference is less than 30 minutes.
End If
```

In that case, `myDateTime` may have been the value of `Date.Now` that you stored earlier or it may have been constructed in some other way.

Hmmm... I read the question again and it seems that you contradict yourself.  First you say that you want to know whether the difference is less than 30 minutes and then you say that you want to return `True` if the difference is exactly 30 minutes.  Perhaps you could make up your mind and get back to us because it's hard to provide a single answer to two contradictory questions.